# How to use dlsym to get function pointer for an Objective-C method

Tags: objective-c, dlsym

I can't find any example online that uses dlsym to load a Objc method symbol.

I can get class though, using something like

`dlsym(handler, "OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager")`

But I don't know how to get a method symbol.

Answer (score 0):

`objc_getClassImplementation`
or `objc_msgSend()`
if you really want to use stuff like `dlsym`; otherwise, you might to analyze the Mach-O at runtime by yourself